# How to integrate Spree in an existing Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have an existing Rails app and a conceptual question.

How do I integrate Spree into this app?

1.) Do I need to install spree, and mount the engine on the routes at a different route? Example:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
```

2.) Or do I need to put my existing views / methods into Spree and make Spree the whole app?